# browserstack upload zip failing with TypeError: can not read property '_byteDispatched' of null, inside zipUpload.js

Tags: gitlab, cypress, browserstack

Browsertack Gitlab CI failing with
TypeError: can not read property '_byteDispatched' of null, inside node_modules/browserstack-cypress-cli/bin/helpers/zipUpload.js

I am using `BrowserStack-cypress-cli: 1.18.0 cypress-file-upload: 5.0.8 cypress: 10.3 extract-zip: 2.1`

and using below commands

```
./BrowserStackLocal --key $BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY --local-identifier $LOCAL_IDENTIFIER --proxy-host $PROXY_HOST --proxy-port $PROXY_PORT --proxy-pass $PROXY_PASSWORD --enable-logging-for-api 

browserstack-cypress run --sync ${test_spec_path} --key $BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY -cf $test_config_path  --env TEST_USER_NAME=$TEST_USER_NAME,TEST_PASSWORD=$TEST_PASSWORD,TEST_ENDPOINT=$TEST_ENDPOINT
```

run --sync command inside pipeline with accesskey etc all needed

Answer (score 0):

As your BrowserStack-cypress CLI version is above V1.11.0, try passing *"cach_dependencies": "false"* in *run_settings* in **browserstack.json**

```
{
  "run_settings": {
    ...
    "cache_dependencies": "false"
  }
}
```

Refer [this](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/cypress/npm-packages#npm-dependency-caching) for clarifications